# Find the determinant of $I + A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What is the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix $B=A+I$, where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $A$ is the $n\times n$ matrix 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @EugenCovaci:  I have tried to expand the determinant using combinatorial technique....but i'm unable to find a solution....... How to find...?.....

Comment: If you haven't seen eigenvalues I have posted an answer expanding the determinant

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a proof using eigenvalues, wishing you have already seen this notion.

Clearly, as all the columns of $A$ are proportional, the kernel has dimension $n-1$, thus eigenvalue $0$ is of order $n-1$.

The sum of the eigenvalues being equal to the trace $\sum_i a_i$, the $n$-th eigenvalue is:

$$\lambda:=\sum_i a_i.$$

Thus as the spectrum of $A+xI$ is equal to the spectrum of $A$ shifted by x (here with $x=1$), it is constituted of $1$ (with multiplicity $n-1$) and $\lambda+1$.

The determinant of a matrix being equal to the product of its eigenvalues, the final result is:

$$\det(A+I)=1+\sum_i a_i$$

Answer (score 15):

Using the [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),

$$\det \left({\bf I}_n + {\bf 1}_n {\bf a}^{\top} \right) = \det \left( 1 + {\bf a}^{\top} {\bf 1}_n \right) = 1 + {\bf a}^{\top} {\bf 1}_n = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$

Comment: No proof can be shorter ! [+1] Besides, thanks for the editing det $\rightarrow$ \det.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer uses the matrix determinant lemma more than the (linked) Sylvester's determinant identity.  Viewing this several years after it was posted, I wonder if the linked Wiki page has changed?

Comment: @Yly Indeed, it did change. Thank you for the notification. Now, Wikipedia calls it the Weinstein–Aronszajn identity. I will try to find a book and cite the book rather than Wikipedia.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for clarifying.  FWIW, the matrix determinant lemma gives the same result, is less of a mouthful than "Weinstein–Aronszajn", and the corresponding Wiki page is probably stable on account of not being named for a person....

Comment: @Yly Edited. If Terry Tao [calls](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities) it the Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity, that is good enough for me.

Answer (score 10):

First look at what happens when $n=2$, $n=3$, renaming our matrix $B_n(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ one gets

$$\begin{align}\det{B_2(a_1,a_2)}&=1+a_1+a_2\\\det{B_3(a_1,a_2,a_3)}&=1+a_1+a_2+a_3\end{align}$$

Assume that $\det{B_{n-1}(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1})}=1+a_1+\cdots a_{n-1}$ and consider

$$\begin{vmatrix}1+a_1    &  a_2   & \cdots & a_n\\
                   a_1    & 1+a_2  & \cdots & a_n\\
                   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
                   a_1    &   a_2  & \cdots & 1+a_n
\end{vmatrix}$$

Substract the second row from the first to get

$$\begin{vmatrix}  1      &  -1    & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
                   a_1    & 1+a_2  & a_3 &\cdots & a_n\\
                   a_1 & a_2 & 1+a_3 & \cdots & a_n\\
                   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
                   a_1    &   a_2  & a_3 &\cdots & 1+a_n
\end{vmatrix}$$

Then add the first column to the second and get

$$\begin{vmatrix}  1      &  0    & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
                   a_1    & 1+a_1+a_2  & a_3 &\cdots & a_n\\
                   a_1 & a_1+a_2 & 1+a_3 & \cdots & a_n\\
                   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
                   a_1    &   a_1+a_2  & a_3 &\cdots & 1+a_n
\end{vmatrix}$$

Developing along the first row one gets

$$\det{B_n(a_1,\cdots,a_n)}=\det{B_{n-1}(a_1+a_2,\cdots ,a_n)}$$

And this by the induction assumption is $$1+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$$