calculating the determinant of a matrix with $1+a_i$ on the main diagonal
How should we verify the following determinant equality?
$$
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1+a_{1} & a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n} \\
a_{1} & 1+a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{1} & a_{2} & \cdots & 1+a_{n}
\end{array}\right|=1+a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}
$$
I attempted subtracting the first row from all other rows, resulting in an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ identity block. However, I still couldn't utilize the Laplace extension to derive the result.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970825/find-the-determinant-of-i-a

You already got
$$
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1+a_{1} & a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n} \\
a_{1} & 1+a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{1} & a_{2} & \cdots & 1+a_{n}
\end{array}\right|
\\
=
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1+a_{1} & a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n} \\
-1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-1 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{array}\right|
$$
by subtracting row $1$ from row $2$, from row $3,\ldots$ and from row $n.$ Now add column $2$ to column $1$, column $3$ to column $1, \ldots$ column $n$ to column $1$ and you get $$=
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1+a_{1} + a_{2} \cdots + a_{n} & a_{2} & \cdots & a_{n}\\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{array}\right|\\=1+a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}
$$
after doing Laplace expansion along the first column.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\mathbf{1}&\cdots&a_n\mathbf{1}\end{pmatrix}$. Recall $\det(A-xI)=\text{ch}_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $\det(A+I)$ is your required matrix, so it suffices for us to consider $\text{ch}_A(-1)$.
First, consider $\text{ch}_A(x)$. Note that $A$ is a rank 1 matrix, so 0 is an eigenvalue of $A$. Moreover, $\ker(A)$ is a $n-1$ dimension space by rank-nullity, so $x^{n-1}|\text{ch}_A(x)$ as the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is greater than the geometric multiplicity of $0$, i.e. $$\text{ch}_A(x)=(-1)^nx^{n-1}(x+b)$$
where  $b$ is some to-be-determined number in $\mathbf{k}$. But how to find $b$? Recall $\text{tr}A$ is just the sum of all eigenvalues of $A$, so $0+0+\cdots+0+(-b)=\text{tr}A=a_1+\cdots+a_n$. This gives $$\text{ch}_A(x)=(-1)^nx^{n-1}(x-(a_1+\cdots+a_n))$$
Now, $\text{ch}_A(-1)=a_1+\cdots+a_n+1.$

The first step you describe seems like a good one. Having done it, now subtract multiples of the other rows from the first row. Each time you do that you will zero out one element in the first row, and add a term to the top left element. When it's all done your top row will be $(1+a_1+\cdots+a_n \quad 0 \quad 0 \quad \ldots \quad 0)$ and the rest of the diagonal will be 1s, and then you're done.
